# testing padrino post methods are stopped by csrf

Tags: ruby, sinatra, minitest, padrino, rack-test

I have a padrino controller with a single post method and a single get method. I can use rack-test to test the get method but not the post method. When I am testing the request returns 403. I think this is because of padrino's built in csrf protection because when I comment out the line with `set :protect_from_csrf, true` I can test the post route. Obviously I don't want to comment out this line as csrf is useful. How can I get temporary access to test these routes for the purpose of testing?

**Controller**

```
SailPowerCourses::Admin.controllers :owners do

  get :index do
    puts 'hello'
  end

  post :index do
    puts params
  end

end
```

**Test**

```
class OwnersControllerTest < MiniTest::Test

  def setup
    app SailPowerCourses::Admin
  end

  def test_creates_an_owner
    email = 'test@example.com'
    assert_empty Owner
    post '/owners', owner: {email: email}
    puts last_response.status
    refute_empty Owner

  end

  def test_other
    email = 'test@example.com'
    get '/owners', owner: {email: email}
  end
end
```

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up an app in minitest you can use a block to access and change settings. such as csrf protection. I found the best solution to be the following. in test_config.rb I set up a version of the app with csrf protection off.

```
class OwnersControllerTest < MiniTest::Test

  def setup
    app SailPowerCourses::Admin do
      set :protect_from_csrf, false
    end
  end

  def test_creates_an_owner
    email = 'test@example.com'
    assert_empty Owner
    post '/owners', owner: {email: email}
    puts last_response.status
    refute_empty Owner

  end

  def test_other
    email = 'test@example.com'
    get '/owners', owner: {email: email}
  end
end
```